# Is it possible to increase keyboard first launch performance in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance

There is always a delay (2-3seconds) on the first time the keyboard got invoked in application. Is there a method or a trick to improve this experience? I tried to use NSTreading, but it crashes on error "only perform on Main Thread" if I use [textfield becomeFirstResponder]; Any ideas?

Comment: Use Instrument's CPU time profiler to see what the app is doing the first time you bring up the keyboard. It may not be the keyboard at all.

Comment: @BergQuester well, I just set the text field to visible and set to the first responder. That's all. And if I run the same thing for the second and third time, it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, do not try to touch UI elements from a background thread unless the documentation specifically states that it is thread-safe.

In your case, attempting to preload the keyboard in the background will not work. Keep in mind that the keyboard isn't created just within your application — it's shared across the system. That means if the system decides it needs to clear up some memory it will most likely "uncache" the keyboard if it's not visible.

If this is occurring in the Simulator, that's most likely because you're quitting the Simulator after every test run. As a result, the keyboard has to be loaded each time you run a test. If this is happening on a device, however, then most likely your device is frequently running low on memory.

That being said, if the instant showing is incredibly important, you could always try to use the old trick of making an invisible `UITextField` first responder, then immediately resigning first responder in order to force the keyboard to load.

Comment: Yes, I can use that trick. However I have an animation played to show the text field. If I trigger the keyboard before the animation code, the thread seems to be blocked and there will be a delay on animation which is not very good in experience either. As I said the delay happens on only the first time that keyboard shows. I understand it cannot be avoid if the system is designed to be like this. I just want to know if there are some tricks I can use. Invisible text field is a good one, but don't work in this case.

Comment: There's no way around it, unfortunately. If you're noticing a thread block it's quite likely they're loading the keyboard on the main thread. The only thing you can do is figure out when your app will be momentarily idle, then take that opportunity to force the keyboard to load.

Answer (score -2):

maybe try a different keyboard? or try going into setting and looking at the input options, and go to keyboard. most of the time its because the programming is lagging, or you have more programms running in the background